# Android date is incorrect

Tags: java, android, calendar

I am using `Calendar` class to get year, month and day:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

this.current_year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
this.current_month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
this.current_day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

Toast.makeText(this.context, this.current_year + "-" + this.current_month + "-" + this.current_day, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Today is 11 Dec 2021 (2021-12-11). But toast alert shows 2021-11-11. Also I tried to set calendar time to a new `Date` class but still wrong

Comment: Calendar returns months starting at 0 not 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

> I am using `Calendar` class

**Don’t.**

Use only *java.time* classes.

```
LocalDate.now( ZoneId.systemDefault() ).getYear()
```

> 2021

## Details

The [Answer by Modi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70314718/642706) is correct.

Furthermore, **never use `Calendar`**. That terrible class was built by people who did not understand date-time handling. Along with `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat`, these classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes.

Specify a time zone to determine date. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by time zone. May be tomorrow in Japan  while simultaneously yesterday in Canada .

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
```

Interrogate for parts.

Unlike the legacy classes, the *java.time* classes use sane numbering. Year 2021 is 2021, and so on. Months are 1-12 for January through December.

```
int year = ld.getYear() ;
int month = ld.getMonthValue() ;
int day = ld.getDayOfMonth() ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Calendar.MONTH returns value start from 0 to 11. (like 0 for Jan, 1 for Feb). So, for showing current month value, you have to +1 in current_month. Your final Toast looks like,

```
Toast.makeText(this.context, this.current_year + "-" + (this.current_month+1) + "-" + this.current_day, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

It will show the result you want.